Indoor Navigation: I am getting path in Unity Editor but when I build and run in android physical device I can't see the path?
I have designed a 3D Model having a floor and two cylinders (for rounded pillars) in unity. I have written a script for navigation but i am unable to see the navigation path in android device whereas I am getting navigation line in unity editor.
There are two script files which I am using:

NavigationTarget.cs
using UnityEngine;
public class NavigationTarget : MonoBehaviour {
}

NewIndoorNav.cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Unity.AI.Navigation;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
public class NewIndoorNav : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField] private Transform player;
[SerializeField] private ARTrackedImageManager m_TrackedImageManager;
[SerializeField] private GameObject trackedImagePrefab;
[SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;
private List navigationTargets = new List();
private NavMeshSurface navMeshSurface;
private NavMeshPath navMeshPath;
private GameObject navigationBase;
private void Start() {
navMeshPath = new NavMeshPath();
 // disable screen dimming
 Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;

}
private void Update() {
if (navigationBase != null && navigationTargets.Count > 0 && navMeshSurface != null) {
//navMeshSurface.BuildNavMesh();
NavMesh.CalculatePath(player.position, navigationTargets[0].transform.position,  NavMesh.AllAreas, navMeshPath);
     if (navMeshPath.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete) {
         line.positionCount = navMeshPath.corners.Length;
         line.SetPositions(navMeshPath.corners);
     } else {
         line.positionCount = 0;
     }
 }

}
private void OnEnable() => m_TrackedImageManager.trackablesChanged.AddListener(OnChanged);
private void OnDisable() => m_TrackedImageManager.trackablesChanged.RemoveListener(OnChanged);
private void OnChanged(ARTrackablesChangedEventArgs eventArgs) {
foreach (var newImage in eventArgs.added) {
navigationBase = GameObject.Instantiate(trackedImagePrefab);
     navigationTargets.Clear();
     navigationTargets = navigationBase.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<NavigationTarget>().ToList();
     navMeshSurface = navigationBase.transform.GetComponentInChildren<NavMeshSurface>();
 }

 foreach (var updatedImage in eventArgs.updated) {
     navigationBase.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(updatedImage.pose.position,    Quaternion.Euler(0, updatedImage.pose.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0));
 }

 foreach (var removedImage in eventArgs.removed) {
 }

}
}


I am new to Unity and AR concept. Don't know where to find the solutions.
